# Customizing Password Reminder View in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have different types of users and i want to send them emails for password recovery,
current email loads a view with a link with token like:

```
Click here to reset your password: {{ url('password/reset/'.$token) }}
```

I want this email to be customized for type of user because i have different routes to respond while this email 
view contains a single route to return.

Like for user:

```
Click here to reset your password: {{ url('user/password/reset/'.$token) }}
```

and for admin

```
Click here to reset your password: {{ url('admin/password/reset/'.$token) }}
```

```
What is the best way of doing it? where exactly i can change to load a view other than remainder view.

Answer (score 0):

To use another view for password resetting in Laravel 5, you can change the content of `auth.password.email` config. The config is saved at `config/auth.php` file.

In your custom view, you can edit the link based on the user type as normal.